# Issues redirecting old site URLs to new site URLs with NGINX

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx

I have been attempting to change the base URLs in my Atlassian stack with only minor success. Ubuntu server 16.04LTS with Nginx reverse proxy. Internal and outside IPs are assigned to different NICs. Yes, this same question is posted on stackoverflow, but I figured I'll try to get max exposure on this one.

Sample Nginx server file:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  listen                443 ssl;
  server_name           projects.old-site.com;
  access_log            off;
  return 301 $scheme://projects.new-site.com;
}

server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           projects.new-site.com;
  access_log            off;

  client_max_body_size  100M;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen                443 ssl;
  server_name           projects.new-site.com;

  client_max_body_size  100M;

  ssl_certificate       /path/to/new-site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /path/to/new-site.key;

location /
...output omitted
```

What works: HTTP redirects and HTTP to HTTPS redirects. http://projects.old-site.com properly redirects to https://projects.new-site.com. Direct access by typing just http://projects.new-site.com (also properly redirects to HTTPS).

What does not: https://projects.old-site.com to https://projects.new-site.com redirection.

Even stranger, when attempting to access https://projects.old-site.com to test the redirect, browsers are not only still being served .old-site.com, but they're being served the expired SSL certificate for that domain.

Nowhere in my system are the expired certificates accessible on this server. I followed the Atlassian URL update guide, changing only the server.xml files, and from within the application administration screens (when they're accessible). All DNS servers are pointing to the correct IPs. I am definitely missing something, but am at a loss. This has been repeated on two different Ubuntu 16.04 servers with Nginx and the same versions of Atlassian software installed.

Please help.

Comment: projects.old-site.com and old-site.com are their own separate server entities, and have to be handled as separate items.  Consider that old-site.com might be handled by a separate server configuration directive in nginx, or may point at a completely different server even.  Also consider ***each server block serving SSL needs to have ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key directives*** or you get SSL cert issues.  (There's many different problems with your configs, by the way...)

Comment: Updated for accuracy. Please explain the problems, that's what I am here for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some problems with your configurations.

We'll go through each individual server block here individually.

---

**Block #1: projects.old-site.com -> projects.new-site.com redirection**

This is what you provided us:

```
server {
    listen                80;
    listen                443 ssl;
    server_name           projects.old-site.com;
    access_log            off;
    return 301 $scheme://projects.new-site.com;
}
```

You're missing a ***lot*** of things here for configuration:

- `ssl_certificate` directive - necessary to know what SSL cert to serve for the domain.
- `ssl_certificate_key` directive - the SSL Certificate key file that corresponds with the SSL cert for the 'old' projects site.

You're doing a 301 redirect to match the scheme, but why are you doing this if you direct non-SSL to SSL in server block 2?  Just redirect to the HTTPS site, *and* include the `$request_uri` for obvious reasons (you don't pass the same request URI through, so things don't work proper).

Your *correct* server block here should look more like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name projects.old-site.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/valid/projects.old-site.com/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/valid/projects.old-site.com/certificate.key;

    access_log off;
    return 301 https://projects.new-site.com$request_uri;
}
```

---

**Block #2: http -> https redirection for projects.new-site.com**

You gave us this:

```
server {
    listen                80;
    server_name           projects.new-site.com;
    access_log            off;

    client_max_body_size  100M;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

You don't have many issues here, but let's try *not* accepting `$host` globally here (we don't need it, we know where we want it to end up), and we don't need `client_max_body_size` either.  301 redirects don't respect that anyways.

You *should* end up with this:

```
server {
    listen                80;
    server_name           projects.new-site.com;
    access_log            off;

    return 301 https://projects.new-site.com$request_uri;
}
```

---

**Block #3: `https://projects.new-site.com`**

Now for your third block.  ***Without the entire server block and all of its configuration directives, we cannot properly assist with configuring the block.**

You gave us this:

```
server {
    listen                443 ssl;
    server_name           projects.new-site.com;

    client_max_body_size  100M;

    ssl_certificate       /path/to/new-site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /path/to/new-site.key;

    ...
}
```

There's nothing really wrong with this block, however unless you *need* the `client_max_body_size` directive for your backend application, you should probably remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I have been working with this server for a while now, inherited to me when I started working here. Yes, the back end application needs the client_max_body_size directive, so I'll have to leave that alone. I will test this out, and report the results.

Comment: Indeed I was missing the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key directives for the old site. Funny how Nginx's own website doesn't mention that when I was researching this issue there. Many thanks, sir.

Comment: @jrea I'm glad this helped solve the problem!  Yeah, the rule of thumb that is unspoken is that "Every site serving SSL should have its own SSL certificate directives defined" in order to make sure that the proper certs are served.